# Parse SDK - [PFUser Logout] throwing NULL exception even though there is a currently logged in user

Tags: ios, sdk, parse-platform

I'm unsure of what's going on.  This code worked earlier (as in this morning) and I haven't done any changes to the Parse SDK or my login methods to change anything, but now I'm getting this error:

2014-09-19 16:00:35.199 OTC[2886:4403] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)'

This is the code I used:

```
- (void)logOutUser
{
  if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
      [PFUser logOut];
  } else {
      NSLog(@"currentUser: %@", [PFUser currentUser]);
  }
}
```

Nothing ground breaking here, I'm just baffled as to why I get the exception thrown at me.  I have several calls throughout my app that rely on a currently logged in user and they all work so there is a current user object there, I just can't seem to log out.  Any pointers would really help out.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is where your app is crashing? Have you set an exception breakpoint?

Comment: Nevermind, goofball mistake.  Like you suggested, there was something else in the program causing the error.  Apparently I had some calls referring to the current user that were getting called, hence the errors.  Thanks for the pointer!